# How to replace multiple values in json file using jq and returning the whole content

Tags: json, linux, yaml, jq

I have a json like this

```
[{"version": 0.0,"Resources": [ {"TargetService": {"Type": "AWS::ECS::Service","Properties": {"TaskDefinition": "abc","LoadBalancerInfo": {"ContainerName": "def","ContainerPort": 8080}}}} ]}]
```

My attempt is to replace **TaskDefinition** key value from "abc" to  "123" and **ContainerName** key value from "def" to "456 in one command and return the whole update json.

This is what i tried

```
echo $APP_SPEC | jq --arg TASK_DEFINITION "123" '(.[].Resources[].TargetService | select(.Properties)).TaskDefinition |=$TASK_DEFINITION')
```

But the substistuion is not happening properly and the value gets appended at the end of the josn as below.

Incorrect response:

```
[ { "version": 0, "Resources": [ { "TargetService": { "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service", "Properties": { "TaskDefinition": "abc", "LoadBalancerInfo": { "ContainerName": "container_name", "ContainerPort": 8080 } }, "TaskDefinition": "123" } } ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the update operator `|=`

```bash
.[].Resources[].TargetService.Properties |= (
  .TaskDefinition = "123"
  | .LoadBalancerInfo.ContainerName = "456"
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1S_Uuj5uis1)

---

Note that `select` only filters its input, it does not descend into the filter criterion. So, if you only want to make the update if the `.Properties` field exists, use `select` **and** descend into it.

```bash
( .[].Resources[].TargetService
  | select(.Properties).Properties
) |= (
  .TaskDefinition = "123"
  | .LoadBalancerInfo.ContainerName = "456"
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_NCxc2ZulJE)

---

Note that the filter `select(.Properties)` will produce `false` if the content of that field, albeit existing, evaluates to `null` or `false`. If you want to consider such cases also as "existent", use `has` in the `select` filter to test for it.

```bash
( .[].Resources[].TargetService
  | select(has("Properties")).Properties
) |= (
  .TaskDefinition = "123"
  | .LoadBalancerInfo.ContainerName = "456"
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zM-CIVTdCPh)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `select`, you can specify the path directly:

```
.[].Resources[].TargetService.Properties.TaskDefinition = "123"
| .[].Resources[].TargetService.Properties.LoadBalancerInfo.ContainerName = "456"
```

Or group by the top level property:

```
.[].Resources[].TargetService.Properties |= (
    .TaskDefinition |= "123"
    | .LoadBalancerInfo.ContainerName |= "456"
)
```

It's also possible to recursively merge the expected object into your existing object using [`*=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Multiplication,division,modulo:*,/,and%):

```
.[].Resources[].TargetService.Properties *= {
    TaskDefinition: "123",
    LoadBalancerInfo: {
        ContainerName: "456"
    }
}
```

Output of all three variants:

```json
[
  {
    "version": 0,
    "Resources": [
      {
        "TargetService": {
          "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
          "Properties": {
            "TaskDefinition": "123",
            "LoadBalancerInfo": {
              "ContainerName": "def",
              "ContainerPort": 456
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: FYI https://jqplay.org/s/9TvwaJgs3_v

Comment: @t0mm13b that's very odd; it works for me when entered into a fresh page: https://jqplay.org/s/Fccx82UUPtv – it looks like you got some carriage returns into the input which will confuse jqplay

Comment: Odd indeed, notepad++ must have buggered up the json formatting with its own plugin. Mea culpa, thanks for the reply @knittl :)

Answer (score 0):

Both the above solutions works perfectly fine. Thanks @Knittl and @pmf. For others who are stuck with this kind of problem here is my complete command to pass two variables to jq and replace the values in one shot.

```
echo $APP_SPEC | jq --arg TASK_DEFINITION "$NEW_TASK_DEFINITION_ARN" --arg CONTAINER_NAME "$CONTAINER_NAME" '.[].Resources[].TargetService.Properties |= (.TaskDefinition = $TASK_DEFINITION | .LoadBalancerInfo.ContainerName = $CONTAINER_NAME )'
```